# Make mapped out portion of a div transparent

Tags: javascript, css

[image]
I want to make something like this in the above image with just 2 `divs` and an `img`. I actually did the one above but I have to use about 6 `divs`.

Is there a way of making a mapped out area of the parent `div` transparent with CSS or JavaScript.

**NB:** The middle square `div` is draggable and resizable.

Comment: Have you considered having two `<div>`s, each with the same background image, but one faded and the other adjustable in size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used three div in this snippet: a background image div, a background overlay (for the tint), and a cropped region.

The cropped region has the same background-image set as the background image div, but the background position is set to the negative div position values.

```js
const cropDiv = document.querySelector(".croppedRegion");

let setCropRegion = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  cropDiv.style.backgroundPositionX = `${-x1}px`;
  cropDiv.style.backgroundPositionY = `${-y1}px`;
  cropDiv.style.width = `${x2-x1}px`;
  cropDiv.style.height = `${y2-y1}px`;
  cropDiv.style.left = `${x1}px`;
  cropDiv.style.top = `${y1}px`;
}

setCropRegion(10, 10, 240, 240);
```

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
}

.backgroundImg {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.PNG');
  
  position:relative;
}

.backgroundOverlay {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.croppedRegion {
  width:110px;
  height:80px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ed/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.PNG');
  
  background-size:250px 250px;
  background-position:-80px -90px;
  position:absolute;
  top:90px;
  left:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundImg">
  <div class="backgroundOverlay">
    <div class="croppedRegion"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer helped.